jSONPath apply filter on a nested criteria within an array & retrive output from within matched array content
We have the following scenario, where we need to extract active flag from phones, only when it's an iPhone.
So essentially, parent.phones (if it contains an iphone) – extract the active flag.
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "parent": {
        "phones": [ 
            {
            "active": "true",
             "phoneDetails": {
                "type": "iPhone",
                "number": "0123-4567-8888"
                }
            },
            {
                "active": "false",
              "phoneDetails": {
                "type": "home",
                "number": "0123-4567-8910"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Tried many options, believe this is the closest,  but it doesn't work either.  Any thoughts on how to get it working?
$.parent.phones[?(@.phoneDetails.[?(@.type] == 'iPhone') ].active

Expected output is "true".

I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  You don't need a nested query.
$.parent.phones[?@.phoneDetails.type == 'iPhone'].active

This returns a value of true from the location $['parent']['phones'][0]['active'] in your original data.
You can try this out at https://json-everything.net/json-path, which is a playground for my implementation (RFC9535).
